# Force http page on ASP.NET MVC IIS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have a web site that runs primarily in https.  I have a couple of pages that have to interact with hardware that must run in http.  I'm using an override of ActionLink to specify protocol of http.  I see http as the link in the browser console.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Set Up WiFi", "setupWiFi", "Utility", "http", null, null, null, null)
```

The problem (maybe it's with IIS 8.5) is the link keeps coming up https.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do something like this using the stock `HtmlHelper` extension methods, but you can use the same link-generation framework the `HtmlHelper` `ActionLink` extension method is using. Under the covers, `ActionLink` uses a static method named `GenerateLink`, which *does* allow you to supply a protocol name:

```
public static string GenerateLink(RequestContext requestContext, RouteCollection routeCollection, string linkText, string routeName, string actionName, string controllerName, string protocol, string hostName, string fragment, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
```

So, using this method (which emits a string) coupled with the `HtmlHelper` class' ability to emit raw HTML using the `Raw` method, you can write your overridden links:

```
@Html.Raw(HtmlHelper.GenerateLink(
  ViewContext.RequestContext, 
  Html.RouteCollection, 
  "My Link Text Here", null, 
  "ActionNameHere", 
  "ControllerNameHere", 
  "http", 
  null, 
  null, 
  null, 
  null))
```

Answer (score 0):

I turns out a previous programmer had implemented a URL rewrite routine in Global.asax.cs file, in the Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute method.  It was taking all URL's and rewriting them as https.

@Andy Hopper The original `@Html.ActionLink("Set Up WiFi", "setupWiFi", "Utility", "http", null, null, null, null)` produces a correct http:// link.